# Primary keys in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here some problems undersanding how this works.
So I have 2 tables Students and Enrolled like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Students 
 (sid CHAR(20), 
 name CHAR(50), 
 email CHAR(30), 
 age INTEGER, 
 gr INTEGER) 

CREATE TABLE Enrolled 
 (sid CHAR(20), 
 cid CHAR(20), 
 grade CHAR(2), 
PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid))
```

So I don't understand this particulary row `PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid)`
Can someone explain to me how it works? I have to specify that I have another table Courses from where the `cid.`

Is is equivalent saying like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled
(sid CHAR(20) foreign key references Students(sid),
cid CHAR(20) foreign key references Courses(cid)
)
```

Comment: There can only be one primary key. How come you can set two primary keys?

Comment: @aliasm2k: This is only one primary key, refering 2 columns.

Comment: Ooh my bad. Seems like I'll have to start over with SQL again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PRIMARY KEY` is used to identify a table. A field or column that is defined as `PRIMARY KEY` will contains different values on each row in that table, and is mandatory to have a value (so, `PRIMARY KEY` is equivalent to `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`).

`PRIMARY KEY` can be a single field, or multiple fields, but it always satisfy that "each row will have a different `PRIMARY KEY`".

If you declare as `PRIMARY KEY` a combination of 2 columns, you will be able to have this for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled 
 (sid CHAR(20), 
 cid CHAR(20), 
 grade CHAR(2), 
PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid)) --PRIMARY KEY with combination of 2 columns
```

---

```
sid   |   cid   |   grade
1          1         XX
1          2         XX
2          1         XX
2          2         XX
2          3         XX
```

In this example, you can see that the column `sid` or the column `cid` has repeated values individually, but there isn't a combination of `(sid, cid)` that was repeated.

Like a `PRIMARY KEY` is used to identify a row in a table, when we want to relate two tables we can define a `FOREIGN KEY` in one table to link this one with the other table.

Your case is that the `ENROLLED` table is identified by a composite `PRIMARY KEY` to represent a many-to-many relationship. That is the way to say that:

- A student can be enrolled in many courses.
- A course can have enrolled many students.

[image]

Note*: Is a best practice to define the `PRIMARY KEYS` as numeric values, such `integer`, `bigint`, etc. because it is better to improve the indexes performance (all `PRIMARY KEYS` have defined inherently an `INDEX`, and they are faster working with "numeric" values than working with "string" values).

Answer (score 1):

`PRIMARY KEY` means both `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`.

If you want `sid` and `cid` to also be `FOREIGN KEY` you have to specify that separately.

Having two fields for a primary key is often used for tables that are the physical representation of a many-to-many relation. In your database design diagram you would have `STUDENT` and `COURSE` as entities and `ENROLLMENT` as a many-to-many relationship between them.

In the physical database diagram many-to-many relationships are modelled as tables, often with a composite `PRIMARY KEY` and with `FOREIGN KEY` constraints to the entity tables.

Comment: but I don't understand why I have 2 primary keys?

Comment: You don't. It's 2 columns for 1 primary key, not 2 primary keys.

Comment: And how could I reffer to this primary key having 2 columns?

Comment: Either by name (the database engine usually provides a name if you don't explicitly name it yourself) or by referring to both columns (the same way you would refer to any two columns).

Answer (score 1):

PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid) means composite primary key.. the combination of these field should be unique.